# Unable to get AVAudioPlayer to stop playing

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have a class defined as Music.swift coded as follows:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class Music {

   var isPlaying: Bool = false
   public var backgrndSound = AVAudioPlayer()
      
   func isMusicPlaying() -> Bool {
      isPlaying = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isPlaying")
      return isPlaying
   }
   
   func StartPlaying() {
      let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Music.mp3", ofType: nil)!
      let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
      do {
         self.backgrndSound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
         self.backgrndSound.numberOfLoops = -1
         self.backgrndSound.play()
         UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "isPlaying")
      } catch {
         // couldn't load file :(
      }
   }
   
   func StopPlaying() {
      self.backgrndSound.pause()
      self.backgrndSound.stop()
   }  
}
```

On first load of the app, the music is automatically started with a call to StartPlaying().  That works just fine.  Afterwards I have a settings menu that has a switch for the music play :

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var swMusic: UISwitch!
   var myMusic = Music()
   
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      swMusic.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isPlaying")
   }

   @IBAction func musicSwitch(_ sender: Any) {
      if swMusic.isOn == true {
         // turn on music
         myMusic.StartPlaying()
      } else {
         myMusic.StopPlaying()
      }
   }  
}
```

When I tap the switch it does fire StopPlaying() but the music in the background continues to play despite the tap.

I am not sure why that is, unless the AV object isn't accessible from the original creation and therefore can't stop it properly; but so far I have been unable to figure that out either.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By instantiating a new instance of the `Music` class in `SettingsViewController` you're effectively creating a new `AVAudioPlayer` instance that knows nothing about the one already instantiated.

Consider this code, which contains **static** properties and **class** methods:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class Music 
{

   public static var backgrndSound: AVAudioPlayer?

   // AVAudioPlayer already has an isPlaying property          
   class func isMusicPlaying() -> Bool 
   {
      return backgrndSound?.isPlaying ?? false
   }
   
   class func StartPlaying() 
   {
      let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Music.mp3", ofType: nil)!
      let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
      do 
      {
         backgrndSound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
         backgrndSound?.numberOfLoops = -1
         backgrndSound?.play()
      } 
      catch 
      {
         // couldn't load file :(
      }
   }
   
   class func StopPlaying() 
   {
      backgrndSound?.pause()
      backgrndSound?.stop()
   }  
}
```

then access this using:

```
Music.isMusicPlaying()
Music.startPlaying()
Music.stopPlaying()
```

i.e. you'd not do `var myMusic = Music()`

This way there will always be a single instance of the `AVAudioPlayer`, `Music.backgrndSound`

This sample code changes `backgrndSound` to an optional ... you're effectively creating an unused `AVAudioPlayer` instance that is discarded as soon as you `startPlaying`.

It also removes the unnecessary `isPlaying` property, as `AVAudioPlayer` already has a property for this purpose.

Comment: Darn it, I missed the "class" portion of the func and I had the one static wrong, but I appreciate the help and assistance my friend.  I was definitely trying to keep it encapsulated so I can use it anywhere without having a crap load of spaghetti code.